# How to fetch multiple lines from XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML has tags in this format:

```
<description>1 line
2line 
3line
</description>
```

I'm applying the following XSL:

```
<xsl:value of select="description">
```

And I'm getting only 1st line in output:

```
1 line
```

Can anyone help me how to fetch all the lines within a tag using XSL?

Comment: I am getting proper output: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1yw

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Could you check this one - https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1yw/1
Not able to fetch scm:sql tag

Comment: The question does not match your link, since the issue is selecting a nested element. You had the nesting wrong in <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Group/cdf:Rule/cdf:check/scm:sql"/> as you didn't have the check element

Comment: See answer: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1yw/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is not correct as per XML you missed tag `cdf:check/` it should be like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="cdf:Group/cdf:Rule/cdf:check/scm:sql"/>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I missed that nest element. How to bold text in XSLT? When I use <strong></strong> It is simply writing <strong> instead of making the text bold.

Comment: (a) please don't ask supplementary questions in comments: ask a new question. (b) XSLT doesn't render output, it simply creates result trees containing element nodes.